# How to use CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT with shared DNS cache

Tags: c++, c, linux, curl, dns

I'm using my own pool of CURL easy handles reused in multi threaded application - the goal is to reuse TCP connections and DNS lookups. Every time a handle is returned to the pool `curl_easy_reset` is called on that handle.

At the moment my implementation uses separate local DNS cache for every CURL easy handle. I'm playing with CURL shared interface and shared DNS cache and it seems to work pretty well but I don't understand what is the correct way to set DNS cache timeout?

DNS cache timeout is set on CURL easy handle but the cache is shared. Do I need to set the timeout every time I get a handle from the pool (because of reset called previously) or is cache timeout set only once and remembered until I change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timeout value is actually stored and used per easy handle. Each easy handle thus has its own timeout value, even when the DNS cache is shared. Each easy handle will thus evict a too old entry and re-resolve a name again according to its own value.

When you set the timeout value for an easy handle, that timeout value will "stick" and be used until you set it again to something else. (Like all other options.)

Calling curl_easy_reset() on the handle will of course reset the timeout value for the handle back to its internal default.

Comment: Shouldn't reset revert my timeout value back to the default one? Anyway it is mostly what I see during my testing. It looks like each handle still maintains its own DNS cache and sync with global one only when local entry expires or when new server is accessed.

Comment: Right, I added reset info to the answer now. The handles really share the single instance of the cache, they do not use their own when shared.

Comment: Thanks. It make sense, I was incorrectly interpreting my log output. Btw. do you know if there is any scenario when global DNS cache in shared interface is locked with shared access instead of single access? I have multiple handles accessing the same server. I would expect first handle to use single access level to fill the cache and all other to use shared access level to get cached DNS entry but they are all using single access level all the time.

Comment: The shared access lock is never used. I designed the locking concept and API first with that idea but we've never reached a point (or had enough energy/time) where we found good use for it.